# Compilation Error: onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in 'package.fool' clashes with onActivityResult in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity'

Tags: android, overriding, onactivityresult

I have a simple Activity that i need to implement the method 'onActivityResult' but when I do that it's returned this message about the method i've implemented.

```
onActivityResult(int,int,Intent)  in 'package.fool' clashes with 'onActivityResult(int,int,Intent)' in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity';
```

My Activity:

```
public class Agenda extends AppCompatActivity implements RecycleViewAdapter.Listener, FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener, PreferenceManager.OnActivityResultListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("OnCreate", "----------------------------------------");
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

I think that there are the same override method for more than two classes, according to this information:

[Overrided Methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT1PF.png)

I would be thankfull if someone help me =D.

Comment: did you get this log  OnCreate", "----------------------------------------")?

Comment: Jaydeep, i can't even run the application, this is a compilation error and it doesn't allow to run. If a remove the method `onActivityResult(int,int,Intent)`  and consequently your interface `PreferenceManager.OnActivityResultListener` then the application runs fine. However i need this implementation =/

Comment: put @Override on 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method.

Comment: I've done that but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! 
Actually there was no need to implement: 
`PreferenceManager.OnActivityResultListener`

Because this method is already implicity in the Activity and the fact that i implemented again the same method was causing the error.

Anyway, thanks for the comunity help.